# whats the difference between static constexpr variables and local constexpr variables

Tags: c++, constexpr

Given the following 2 programs what is the difference between using static constexpr variables and local variables

Program 1:

```
class point
{
public:
    constexpr point() = default;
    constexpr point(int x, int y) : x_{x}, y_{y}{}
    constexpr point(point const&) = default;
    constexpr point& operator=(point const&) = default;
    constexpr int x() const noexcept { return x_;}
    constexpr int y() const noexcept { return y_;}
private:
    int x_{};
    int y_{};
};

constexpr point increment_both(point p){
   return {p.x() + 1, p.y() + 1};
}

constexpr point add(point a, point b){
    return {a.x() + b.x(), a.y() + b.y()};
}

constexpr point origin{};
constexpr point pp{33,4};
constexpr point iipoint = increment_both(pp);
constexpr point r = add(pp, iipoint);
constexpr int v = r.x();

int main()
{
    return v;
}
```

Program Listing 2:

```
class point
{
public:
    constexpr point() = default;
    constexpr point(int x, int y) : x_{x}, y_{y}{}
    constexpr point(point const&) = default;
    constexpr point& operator=(point const&) = default;
    constexpr int x() const noexcept { return x_;}
    constexpr int y() const noexcept { return y_;}
private:
    int x_{};
    int y_{};
};

constexpr point increment_both(point p){
   return {p.x() + 1, p.y() + 1};
}

constexpr point add(point a, point b){
    return {a.x() + b.x(), a.y() + b.y()};
}

int main()
{

    constexpr point origin{};
    constexpr point pp{33,4};
    constexpr point iipoint = increment_both(pp);
    constexpr point r = add(pp, iipoint);
    constexpr int v = r.x();

    return v;
}
```

Program listing 1: This emits less code when unomptimised.
main:

```
push    rbp
mov     rbp, rsp
mov     eax, 67
pop     rbp
ret
```

Program 2 emits a heap more
main:

```
push    rbp
mov     rbp, rsp
mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-12], 0
mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 0
mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-20], 33
mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-16], 4
mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-28], 34
mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-24], 5
mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-36], 67
mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-32], 9
mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 67
mov     eax, 67
pop     rbp
ret
```

What are the differences between these. Is using one over the other better?
And why the massive differences in the assembler output.

Thanks.

Comment: the compiler can optimize out all the code in both case. So I'd say no difference here.

Comment: Just a guess (and I don't have the knowledge to give a definite answer), but it's probably because in program 1, you are not executing this code in main(), you're executing that globally. It makes sense it wouldn't be with the main code, I think.

Comment: [here](https://godbolt.org/z/HfNgEC) is an example of `gcc` + `-Os` flag, both compile to the same result. (`-O3` gives same result)

Comment: "whats the difference between static constexpr variables and local constexpr variables" - their lifetimes.